# Who is the one God that James say demons believe? James 2:19

Tags: luke, james, demons

In Luke 8:28, we find that demons also know who Jesus is. Luke 4:3, 9 also tell us that Satan knew who Jesus is. Since we wrestle against the principalities, against the powers, against the world-rulers of this darkness, against the spiritual hosts of wickedness in the heavenly places, it will be interesting to know who is the God that demons and Satan believe and fear.

James 2:19 ASV

> Thou believest that God is one; thou doest well: the demons also believe, and shudder.

Luke 8:28 ASV

> And when he saw Jesus, he cried out, and fell down before him, and with a loud voice said, What have I to do with thee, Jesus, thou Son of the Most High God? I beseech thee, torment me not

Luke 4:3, 9 ASV

> <sup>**3**</sup> And the devil said unto him, if thou art the Son of God, command this stone that it become bread.

> <sup>**9**</sup> And he led him to Jerusalem, and set him on the pinnacle of the temple, and said unto him, If thou art the Son of God, cast thyself down from hence:

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this is a hermeneutical Q as you invoke 3 separate texts, yet there is no question in the initial text (James 2:19) that the other two are related, nor that James gives rise to any doubt as to this one God. Are you not seeking to raise a theological question, directed at those who link demonic trembling at Jesus with the trembling at God in James 2:19? One answer already seems to have taken it that way, in which case this should be migrated to Christianity.

Comment: "directed at those who link demonic trembling at Jesus with the trembling at God in James 2:19? One answer already seems to have taken it that way" No, I have not taken it that way actually. I never said that in my answer.  Is there a problem with my answer, though? I'd genuinely value some constructive criticism. So did I get something wrong?

Comment: Ahh, you know what, I see the problem with my answer... I didn't actually answer the question. My bad.

Comment: Actually @Rajesh did answer the Question, so I undeleted that answer and upvoted it. On some level, this Question seems to be theologically loaded, almost baiting debate because there is an expected answer: the presumed God of the theology of that culture and ancient audience, the Jewish God. To ask "which of many" concerning a monotheist society could create unnecessary tension, especially if this Question takes a theological turn. If that happens, I will pursue my initial thought that the OP is off topic. But with Rajesh's Answer, it clearly isn't. Let's keep awesome by keeping on topic.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I honestly think it could have been much better, but thank you for undeleting it/giving it an upvote. I appreciate it! Have a wonderful day. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the scriptures you quoted. First we'll start with Luke 8:28;

> *"And seeing Jesus, he cried out and fell before Him, and said in a loud voice, "What do I have to do with You, Jesus, Son of the **Most High God**? I beg You, do not torment me."*

They are afraid of the "Most High God", of which they knew Jesus is Son. And who is that other than Yahweh God? In the Hebrew Bible, the "Most High" is an epithet given **solely** to Yahweh God. In Hebrew, it looks like this; עֶלְיוֹן. And it's pronounced "el-yon". Whenever עֶלְיוֹן is used as a noun(masculine), it always refers to Yahweh God. Here are some passages in the Hebrew Bible where God is called *Elyon*, a.k.a. *Most High*.

> [Genesis 14:18-22] "And Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine. He was a priest of God **Most High**. And he blessed him and said, "Blessed be Abram by God **Most High**, Possessor of heaven and earth; and blessed be God **Most High**, who has delivered your enemies into your hand!" And Abram gave him a tenth of everything. And the king of Sodom said to Abram, "Give me the persons, but take the goods for yourself." But Abram said to the king of Sodom, "I have lifted my hand to the Lord, God **Most High**, Possessor of heaven and earth..."

> [Numbers 24:16] "The oracle of him who hears the words of God, And knows the knowledge of the **Most High**, Who sees the vision of the Almighty, Falling down, yet having his eyes uncovered."

> [2 Samuel 22:14] "The LORD thundered from heaven, And the **Most High** uttered His voice."

> [Lamentations 3:34-38] "To crush underfoot all prisoners in the land, to deny people their rights before the **Most High**, to deprive them of justice—would not the Lord see such things? Who can speak and have it happen if the Lord has not decreed it? Is it not from the mouth of the **Most High** that both calamities and good things come?"

And there are, of course, many more. The point is, the "Most High" is an epithet given to the God of the Hebrew Bible, Yahweh. This is the God that the demons fear, and this is the God Satan was talking about when he tempted Jesus to disregard God's will and take matters into his own hands by turning the stone into bread at Luke 4:3;

> *"The devil said to him, "If you are the Son of **God**, tell this stone to become bread.""*

Both the **demons** and the **devil** knew Jesus was the Son of *some* god. And if the demons knew he was the Son of the *Most High God*, then certainly when Satan called Jesus the *Son of God*, he was talking about the very same God, i.e. the Most High(Elyon) God. So, that explains Luke 4:3;9.

And so *that* is the God the demons believe exists(and of which they tremble in fear), as shown in James 2:19;

> *"You believe that God is one. Good for you! Even the **demons** believe that — and **tremble**."*

Hope this helps! Have a good day. :)